# How to display status of Audio playing in React Native Audio?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native Expo app using Audio. I'm trying to update the status of of the file and pass it to the render() functin in the way of moving the slider based on how far the audio has played and how much time is left.

I'm having a difficult time getting this to work.

I previously added

```
//   this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getStatus(), 1000);
```

right after this.loadAudio() in componentDidMount but when I did this, I received a few errors when I went back to another page or if I let the audio run for longer than 5 min...I'd get a javascript heap out of memory error. I also get the error below when I navigate to another page. When I removed this line, I didn't receive this error anymore.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
```

Any advice on how to get this to work?

```
    constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.name = props.navigation.getParam('name');
            this.audio_file = props.navigation.getParam('audio_file');
            this.length = props.navigation.getParam('length');
            this.long_desc = props.navigation.getParam('long_desc');
            this.category = props.navigation.getParam('category');
            this.spotify_link = props.navigation.getParam('spotify_link');
            this.state = {
                isPlaying: false,
                playbackInstance: null,
                currentIndex: 0,
                volume: 1.0,
                isBuffering: false,
                value:0
              };

              this.getStatus = this.getStatus.bind(this);
          }

          async componentDidMount() {
            try {
              await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: false,
                interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_MIX_WITH_OTHERS,
                // interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DUCK_OTHERS,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
                interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS,
                shouldDuckAndroid: true,
                staysActiveInBackground: true,
                playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true
              })
              this.loadAudio();
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e)
            }
          }

          async loadAudio() {
            const {currentIndex, isPlaying, volume} = this.state
            try {
              const playbackInstance = new Audio.Sound()
              const source = {
                uri: this.audio_file
              }
              const status = {
                shouldPlay: isPlaying,
                volume
              }
              playbackInstance.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate)
              await playbackInstance.loadAsync(source, status, false)
              this.setState({playbackInstance})
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
              }
              this.getStatus();
          }

          onPlaybackStatusUpdate = status => {
            this.setState({
              isBuffering: status.isBuffering
            })
          }

          handlePlayPause = async () => {
            const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state;
            isPlaying
              ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
              : await playbackInstance.playAsync()          
            this.setState({
              isPlaying: !isPlaying
            })
          }

          getStatus = async () => {
            const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state;
            var status = await playbackInstance.getStatusAsync();
            var percentage = (status["positionMillis"] / status["durationMillis"] * 100);
            var remainingTime = status["durationMillis"] - status["positionMillis"];

            // For use to move the slider automatically
            this.state.value = percentage;
            console.log(percentage);

            // Convert to mm:ss format
            var milliseconds = remainingTime % 1000;
            var seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) % 60);
            var minutes = Math.floor((remainingTime / (60 * 1000)) % 60);
            remainingTime = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            this.setState({position: percentage, timeLeft: remainingTime});
          }

        // Exit button
          exitScreen = async () => {
            const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state
            isPlaying
              ? await playbackInstance.unloadAsync()
              : null
            this.setState({
              isPlaying: !isPlaying
            })

            // this.getStatus = null;
            this.props.navigation.pop();
          }
```

Comment: https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/blob/master/AudioExample/AudioExample.js

Comment: you can use the above example. use this.state.currentTime as a variable to build slider logic